# Why does $P(A \cap B \mid C) = P(B \mid C) \cdot P(A \mid B \cap C)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-explanation, conditional-probability

I was watching a lecture and there was an equation containing
$P(A \cap B \mid C)$ and the instructor said that this is equal to
$P(B \mid C) \cdot P(A \mid B \cap C)$ and I don't understand this step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just translate into equations. Recall that, by definition, if $P(Y) \ne 0$,

$$P(X \mid Y) = \frac{P(X \cap Y)}{P(Y)}$$

Then, assuming $P(C), P(B\cap C)$ are nonzero,

$$\begin{align*}
P(A \cap B \mid C) &= \frac{P(A \cap B \cap C)}{P(C)}\\
P(B \mid C) \cdot P(A \mid B \cap C) &= \frac{\color{blue}{P(B \cap C)}}{P(C)} \cdot \frac{P(A \cap B \cap C)}{\color{blue}{P(B \cap C)}} \\
&= \frac{P(A \cap B \cap C)}{P(C)} \\
&= P(A \cap B \mid C) 
\end{align*}$$

since the blue factors cancel.